# Troubleshooting UIKit display issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode8

I have a very strange issue where a chart ([SwiftChart](https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart)) is not being displayed (is not visible/rendered) when the project is built and run.

Some background:

- XCode 8 (project was originally and XCode 7 project)
- Objective C project/ViewControllers
- A swift file to render the chart (have tried calling this from viewDidLoad & viewDidLayoutSubviews)
- Storyboard containing all ui elements
- Using CocoaPods
- The 'print' code you see in Swift outputs 'null'

The UIView where the chart is to be rendered exists within the storyboard and is setup as follows
[image]

The code being called is:

```
let chart = Chart()
print(chart.window?.frame.width)
print(chart.window?.frame.height)

let data = [(x: 0.0, y: 0), (x: 3, y: 2.5), (x: 4, y: 2), (x: 5, y: 2.3), (x: 7, y: 3), (x: 8, y: 2.2), (x: 9, y: 2.5)]
let series = ChartSeries(data: data)
series.area = true
chart.xLabels = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24]
chart.xLabelsFormatter = { String(Int(round($1))) + "h" }
chart.add(series)
```

Visually I see nothing. I'm struggling to figure out where the problem might be so any pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: Where is the code called from? `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I've tried viewDidLoad, viewDidLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 2):

You uave to initialize it with a frame when creating it programmatically since it's a `UIControl` subclass. It appears their first code example is wrong but they explain it correctly in the next. All on-screen views need a frame at a minimum.

But if you already have a view of this class in your storyboard you need an outlet to point to it. Your first line of code creates a new one, so you're not talking to the one you set up, but an improperly created off-screen one.

So add an outlet and connect it to your view so you can talk to it.

Comment: I see, thank you. The problem is now that because my ViewController is ObjC I cannot create an outlet to my Swift file.

Comment: That code is in a separate Swift file and is called from an ObjC method that initialises the VC. I'm using bridging for this. So If I try to create an IBOutlet from my storyboard I can only do so to my .h or .m file, not my .swift file. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: It's hard to follow with a partial code listing, but if you must separate things like this, why not pass a reference to the chart view to the function that initializes everything? Then your VC's outlet stays put and is passed to the function for manipulation.